# Open private google sheet in an iframe without Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, iframe

Is there a way to open a private google sheet in an iframe of some other website?

I tried Google Apps Script, it works fine but i don't want to go that route, it has other problems like it displays a banner saying

> This app is not developed by Google.

along with other restrictions

Also i don't want to publish that google sheet, i just want to be able to open it in an iframe as it is with ability to edit and all, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific about what you exactly are trying to achieve? Wouldn't a regular embed (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files&zippy=%2Cedit-embedded-spreadsheets) work? Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to publish the sheet like they do there, the thing is i want users to be able to open their private spreadsheets on my website without them having to make that sheet public or having to publish that sheet to the web

Comment: Well, when you embed a document you have to publish it, but there's no need to make that document public. The document can remain private and inaccessible via link or otherwise. I am not aware of any other possible solution apart from embedding or opening the whole Google Drive page.